# separate regex confusion

Tags: r, tidyverse

```
 a     
 Hello abc AA
 bcc BB
 xaa X
 axd LSE
```

How do I come up with a regex for this dataframe so that I can separate the capitals at the end

```
a          b
Hello abc  AA
bcc        BB
xaa        X
axd        LSE
```

Not sure why this wont work

```
 df %>%
  separate(a, c("a", "b"), " [[:upper:]]+")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use a regex lookaround to do this.  Here, the pattern matched is one or more spaces (`\\s+`) preceding one or more non-white space (`\\S+`) till the end (`$`) of the string

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>%
    separate(a, into = c('a', 'b'), "\\s+(?=\\S+$)")
```

---

Or with OP's pattern i.e. to match one or more spaces (`\\s+`) preceding an upper case letter (`[[:upper:]]` or `[A-Z]`)

```
df %>%
    separate(a, into = c('a', 'b'), "\\s+(?=[[:upper:]])")
#         a   b
#1 Hello abc  AA
#2       bcc  BB
#3       xaa   X
#4       axd LSE
```

---

Or another option is `extract` where we capture as groups

```
df %>% 
    extract(a, into = c('a', 'b'), '^(.*) (\\S+)$')
#          a   b
#1 Hello abc  AA
#2       bcc  BB
#3       xaa   X
#4       axd LSE
```

---

A `base R` option is `strsplit`

```
do.call(rbind, strsplit(df$a, "\\s(?=[A-Z])", perl = TRUE))
```

---

Or with `read.csv`

```
read.csv(text = sub("\\s(?=[A-Z])", ',', df$a, perl = TRUE),
       header = FALSE, col.names = c('a', 'b'))
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(a = c("Hello abc AA", "bcc BB", "xaa X", "axd LSE"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

Comment: I want it to work for something like "Hello There Ok LO" . Splitting "Hello There Ok" and "LO" as well. Didn't work for that case